# Geometric Interpretation of a Matrix Transformation's Eigen Vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I'm having a little bit of an issue grappling how to determine the eigenvalues and eigenvectors of a matrix given that it is a geometric transformation. Take, for instance, the following matrix:

$\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 5 \\ 5 & -12 \end{bmatrix}$
How can I find its eigenvalues/eigenvectors simply by knowing its a reflection-dilation? Likewise, say I had a rotation dilation-- how would I do it then?
Thanks for help.

Comment: The line of reflection is an eigenvector.  It clearly doesn't go anywhere.  And vector perpendicular to the line of reflection is transformed to the negative of itself.  Rotations have complex eigenvectors.

Comment: @DougM right.. so how would I find the eigenvector/value of the given matrix? is there an easier way that's not the normal calculation?

Comment: No, it's usually the other way around: *first* we find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, *then* we can conclude about the geometric nature of the tranaformation.

Comment: @MinnieC Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

If you know what kind of transformation is (reflection/dilatation/rotation) you can determine one or more eigenvalues and eigenvectors directly.

For example $Av=1\cdot v$ indicate the line $vt$ is a fixed line and if for $w\perp v$ we have $Aw=-1\cdot w$ then A is a reflection with respect to the line $vt$.

In your example $A=\begin{bmatrix} 12 & 5 \\ 5 & -12 \end{bmatrix}$ we find

- $\lambda_1=13 \quad v_1=(5,1)$
- $\lambda_1=-13 \quad v_2=(-1,5)$

is indeed a reflection with dilatation with respect to the line $v_1t$.

Answer (score 0):

Frankly, the generic computation so simple and quick for $2\times2$ matrices that I’m not sure that there’s much to be gained by memorizing a bunch of special cases. On the other hand, understanding the eigensystems of various types of transformations certainly isn’t a bad thing.

There are, of course, the properties of eigensystems of square matrices of any order. Here are a few:

- The last eigenvalue comes for “free” because the sum of the eigenvalues is equal to the trace of the matrix.
- Real symmetric matrices have real eigenvalues with orthogonal eigenspaces.
- The only eigenvalues of a projection are $0$ and $1$; it’s the identity map when restricted to its image.
- The only eigenvalues of a reflection are $\pm1$. The eigenspace of $1$ is the subspace that corresponds to the reflector.
- The eigensystem of $aI+b\mathbb 1$ has a particularly simple structure explained many times on MSE.
- A dilation is a multiple of the identity, so has a single eigenvalue—the dilation factor—with the entire space as its eigenspace.

A few $2\times2$ specifics:

- For a rotation matrix $R$, $\operatorname{tr}R = 2\cos\theta$ and its eigenvalues are $e^{\pm i\theta}$ with eigenvectors $(\pm i,1)^T$, respectively.
- The eigenvalues of a conformal matrix $\begin{bmatrix}\alpha&-\beta\\\beta&\alpha\end{bmatrix}$ are $\alpha\pm i\beta$. (Indeed, these matrices are isomorphic to the complex numbers under multiplication.) If you convert these complex eigenvectors into the polar form $re^{i\theta}$, you can see that these matrices correspond to dilated rotations.
- A reflection in the line $x\sin\theta-y\cos\theta=0$ has the form $\begin{bmatrix}\cos{2\theta}&\sin{2\theta}\\\sin{2\theta}&-\cos{2\theta}\end{bmatrix}$. Its eigenvectors are $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)^T$ with eigenvalue $1$ and $(\sin\theta,-\cos\theta)^T$ with eigenvalue $-1$.

You can combine some of these, too. Your example of a dilation/reflection must have the form $$\begin{bmatrix}s\cos{2\theta}&s\sin{2\theta}\\s\sin{2\theta}&-s\cos{2\theta}\end{bmatrix}$$ and its eigenvalues are $\pm s$. You can recover $s$ using the identity $(s\cos{2\theta})^2+(s\sin{2\theta})^2=s^2$, in this case producing $s = \sqrt{12^2+5^2}=13$. You could compute the eigenvectors via the half-angle trigonometric formulas, but as I mentioned at the start the generic method is pretty fast and spits out the eigenvectors $(5,1)^T$ and $(1,-5)^T$ in fairly short order.

For your dilation/rotation, see the case of a conformal matrix, above. Taking, for example, $$\begin{bmatrix}12&5\\-5&12\end{bmatrix},$$ you can immediately write down the eigenvalues $12\pm5i$, and the dilation factor is again $13$.